# Convert bytearray representation to string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following string I am reading from a file: `bytearray(b'\x03\x05\n')`

Whats the easiest way to convert this to a 3-character string (or 3-element list)?

(To be clear: There is a file `a.txt`, whose contents are "`bytearray(b'\x03\x05\n')`")

Comment: As in the file literally starts out `b` `y` `t` `e` etc.? You need to fix the code that produced this file.

Comment: Yes. The file literally is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Why is it literally `"bytearray(b'\x03\x05\n')"`?? Well, okay...

You should execute the code in the file then. This is highly insecure, but simple:

```
data = eval(your_file.read())
```

Now `data` is your `bytearray`.

It's already a kind of three character list as you can access and modify its elements.

If you want a `list` with three numbers (although the data in a `bytearray` *is already* a sequence of numbers), just do:

```
result = list(bytearray(b'\x03\x05\n'))
result == [3, 5, 10] # True
```